# Close Facebook Dialog (popup)

Tags: php, facebook

I am building an facebook app which runs in a tab of a site as an iframe.

for popups I use the recommended stuff from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/):

when i open a popup like so:

```
var friend_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=**appid**&display=popup&redirect_uri=**canvasurl**&message=Mesage!"
window.open(friend_url, "Friends", "height=400,width=580,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");
```

then a dialpg-popup opens.
what I want now. if the user clicks, accept or cancel the dialog window should close.
how can I do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page that you supply as the value of `redirect_uri` can issue the JavaScript command `self.close();` and after the user selects "accept" or "cancel", Facebook will redirect to the supplied `redirect_uri` location, closing the window.  Just make sure to do any processing you need to do re: error handling or processing the response, before you close the window. Once you do, it's gone!

Edited to reflect comment below:

```
var auth_win = window.open(friend_url, "Friends", options);
```

Then you'll need to detect somehow that the user's action is complete, and issue something like:

```
auth_win.close();
```

If you can't detect when the action is complete, there is some disconnect.  If you mean that the redirect_uri is always your tab application, or your canvas URL, then you can add parameters to the query string, i.e. `url?auth=complete` or after a hash, i.e. `url#authorized`.  Then once this is detected, close the window referenced by the variable.

Comment: Then you'll have to do it from the opener:

Comment: how can i detect what the user is pushing?

Comment: You can't tell what buttons are being pressed as you aren't in control of the pop-up content, correct? You need to detect the response from Facebook at the redirect_uri.  It's been a little while since I've done this, what is the value of the `redirect_uri`? (not the exact value, but what does it represent, my canvas URI, etc.?)

Comment: I read the docs referenced above, seems like it's the canvas_url, so you can pass extra info on the query string or as an anchor (hash).

Comment: Although it seems like Facebook should close the window itself after redirecting the top.opener to the redirect_uri. I've never experienced that behavior though.

Comment: canvasurl: www.facebook.com/pages/pagename/pageid?sk=app_appid.
I cannot access the top.location from the app-iframe...

Comment: Have you tried top.opener.top.location? The location property should be visible from the iFrame that was created by it.

Comment: And you can use the JavaScript library to check for authorization from your canvas right? Is the Facebook pop-up actually redirecting the pop-up location, the iFrame location, or the main facebook window location?

Comment: Doesn't work anymore as stated by Mozila's Window.close() specs: "This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method, or on top-level windows that have a single history entry."